# Glassfish entity is not persisted

Tags: jpa, glassfish, ejb, eclipselink, jta

I create table and sequence in PostgreSQL:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE 
    test_id
INCREMENT 1
START 1
MAXVALUE 500;
CREATE TABLE TEST(
    id              NUMERIC PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT NEXTVAL('test_id'),
    name                TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    name2               TEXT DEFAULT NULL
);
```

Then I generate entity in Eclipse:

```
@Entity
@NamedQuery(name="Test.findAll", query="SELECT t FROM Test t")
public class Test implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private long id;
    private String name;
    private String name2;

    public Test() {
    }


    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name="TEST_ID_GENERATOR", sequenceName="TEST_ID", allocationSize=1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="TEST_ID_GENERATOR")
    public long getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }


    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }


    public String getName2() {
        return this.name2;
    }

    public void setName2(String name2) {
        this.name2 = name2;
    }

}
```

Then I try to write my entity in table from servlet:

```
@PersistenceUnit(name="Tets")
EntityManagerFactory emf; 

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
        Test t = new Test();

        t.setName("jdsfjjd");
        t.setName2("jdsfjjd");
        em.persist(t);

        response.getWriter().append("Served at: ").append(request.getContextPath());
    }
```

When i deploy my project and use that servlet, I do not see logs. Project is deploy servlet is start, in browser I see: `Served at: /Tets`, but when I check the table, I do not see my entity there. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: add `em.flush()` after `em.persist(..)`

Comment: i add and catch javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: 
Exception Description: No externally managed transaction is currently active for this thread

Comment: You have to configure a transaction manager

Comment: Thanks for the help. But what do you mean? I use glassfish(payara) i don't understand why when i use no generet strategy for pk, entity is aded, but when i use sequence, trunsuction manager is unturned

Answer (score 0):

The short answer: you misuse application-managed EntityManager.

When you inject an EntityManager in Java EE environment, it's controlled by your IoC container (it's almost always EJB or CDI one). Container handles transactions propagation and demarcation on business method call making any manual actions upon transactional mechanisms needless:

```
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager em;
...
@TransactionAttribute(REQUIRES_NEW)
public void someMethod(Bean b) {
    em.persist(b);
} // Transaction gets committed and em gets flushed with no extra work
```

When you instead inject an EntityManagerFactory, all the magic would be gone. In such case you need to perform transactional binding manually. You do nothing about it and that's the reason you get TransactionRequiredException. The original example throws nothing because there would be no flush without active transaction, so your changes get silently ignored. This would look like so:

```
@Resource
private UserTransaction t;
...
t.begin();
emf.createEntityManager().persist(bean);
t.commit();
```

In this scenario I would suggest you to utilize industry's best practice by using EntityManager injection in conjunction with some stateless bean to maintain EM's thread unsafety. Then inject your EJB into this servlet and do what you need.

The other way would be to inject UserTransaction and call it's begin() method explicitly. UserTransaction is not declared to be thread-safe, so you'll need some kind of synchronization around it's usage. This will definitely kill all the performance so I would suggest you to fall back to the first option.